# How to predict a response for a GLM using my values?

Tags: r

Apologies for any bad English, it is not my first language :)

So I have a dataset of the passengers of the titanic, and produced the following fit summary:

```
glm(formula = Survived ~ factor(Pclass) + Age + I(Age^2) + Sex + 
    Fare + I(Fare^2), family = binomial(), data = titan)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.7298  -0.6738  -0.3769   0.6291   2.4821  

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      4.678e+00  6.321e-01   7.401 1.35e-13 ***
factor(Pclass)2 -1.543e+00  3.525e-01  -4.377 1.20e-05 ***
factor(Pclass)3 -2.909e+00  3.882e-01  -7.494 6.69e-14 ***
Age             -6.813e-02  2.196e-02  -3.102  0.00192 ** 
I(Age^2)         4.620e-04  3.193e-04   1.447  0.14792    
Sexmale         -2.595e+00  2.131e-01 -12.177  < 2e-16 ***
Fare            -9.800e-03  5.925e-03  -1.654  0.09815 .  
I(Fare^2)        2.798e-05  1.720e-05   1.627  0.10373    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 964.52  on 713  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 641.74  on 706  degrees of freedom
  (177 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 657.74

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Now I'm trying to predict the survival probability of a female aged 21 who paid 35 for her ticket fare.

I'm unable to use `predict` or `predict.glm` and am unsure why. I run the following and produce this error:

```
predict(glmfit, data.frame(PClass=2, Sex="female", Age=20), type="response")
```

> Error in factor(Pclass) : object 'Pclass' not found

I then just try to calculate it the long-way, that is by multiplying my coefficients to the desired values but the answer I get there is not right either.

```
(4.678e+00)+(1*-1.543e+00)+(21*-6.813e-02)+((21^2)*4.620e-04)+(35*-9.800e-03)+((35^2)*2.798e-05)
[1] 1.599287
```

Not sure how I could a probability greater than 1, especially when my response is a binomial factor of 0 or 1.

Could someone please shed some light on my mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typo. You fit the model using a `Pclass` (with a lower-case c) variable, but then try to use `PClass` (with a capital C) for prediction. Also, the default link for logistic regression is the logit and not identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the probability by hand, then follow the steps

1. Multiply coefficients to the desired values
2. Take exponential of the output from step 1
3. Probability = output of step 2/(1 + output of step 2)

In your case, the output of step 1 is 1.599287. The output of step 2 will be exp(1.599287) = 4.949502. Then probability = 4.949502/(1 + 4.949502) = 0.8319187.

So, in R you can create your own function like

```
logit2prob <- function(logit){
  odds <- exp(logit)
  prob <- odds / (1 + odds)
  return(prob)
}
```

For more details, you can visit [this](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/convert_logit2prob/).
Otherwise, the suggestion by @Roland should work fine.